# HTML Button's jQuery function is having trouble with MVC FileResult

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

I intended for this function to call my MVC action method that returns a CSV report.

```
$(function() {
    $('#exportButton').click(function() {
        $.get('/curReport/GetCSVReport');
    });
});
```

If I make a button like the code below then, when it is clicked, I'm given the "Open with/Save File" window.

```
<input type="button" value="Export" onClick="location.href='CurReport/GetCSVReport'">
```

However, when I change my button to use my jQuery function then, although `GetCSVReport()` is called I'm not given the "Open with/Save File" window.

Here is my `GetCSVReport()`

```
public FileResult GetCSVReport()
{
    ...
    return fileResult;
}
```

How can I get my jQuery function to work like the `onClick`?

Thank you,

Aaron

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the same code you used before:

```
$(function() {
    $('#exportButton').click(function() {
        location.href = 'CurReport/GetCSVReport';
    });
});
```

`get` triggers an Ajax call, which you do not want here. You use jQuery to bind the event, but the action stays the same.

To add query string parameters, use:

```
location.href = 'CurReport/GetCSVReport?filter=' + escape(val);
```

Comment: How do I add values to the parameters?  Using the old way I could have just done this "$.get('/curReport/GetCSVReport', {filter: val});".  Thank you!

Comment: @Aaron - updated the answer. If `val` has a simple value (eg, number), you don't have to escape it.