# MVC control calling thread after export to excel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, response, export-to-excel

I have the export to excel working by creating a seperate ActionResult that sets the content type of the response stream header to "application/vnd.ms-excel" and also sets the excel file as a "attachment".  Before all this starts, my calling view displays a jquery modal that says "processing...".  Since its a seperate UI thread, is it possible to terminate the modal once the excel file stream has reached the client?  The only way I can think of is by using a javascript timer, but thats not flexible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use javascript to handle the .click of the export button.

Your window.location points to the route of a FileResult type of action.

That will open the download dialog, and you can continue with updating the UI.  That's a "asynchronous" style file export.

Quick StackOverflow search found: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546545/html-buttons-jquery-function-is-having-trouble-with-mvc-fileresult)

Comment: I'm having a little trouble in understanding how the original caller would detect that a download dialog is displayed.  I found [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/GruffCode/archive/2010/10/28/detecting-the-file-download-dialog-in-the-browser.aspx), seems to be a very elegant solution.  I'll accept your answer, since it gave me the insight to go find the other article :)  Thanks.

Comment: I have to say, that's a MUCH more elegant solution.  I bookmarked that and will try it the next time I come up with something like this.